# Meteor – Manipulate a template included in another template after it has been rendered

Tags: meteor

I am trying to manipulate with JS the template `loginButtons` from the package `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` after it has been rendered. That template is included in my template `login` and I am trying to use `Template.login.onRendered` to achieve this manipulation. The problem is that the JS runs before `loginButtons` has been rendered so it is not working as intended.

```
<template name="login">
  <div id="login">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    {{> loginButtons}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.login.onRendered(function () {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").remove();
  $("#login-dropdown-list").addClass("open");
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Add this event to loginButtons template, not login

Comment: Like @Sindis said - your 'loginButtons' DOM elements could be not ready yet. So you should use `Template.loginButtons.onRendered` lifecycle event

Comment: I do not want to run that JS every time I use the `loginButtons` template, only in the `login` template.

Another problem is that `loginButtons` is a template inside a package, and I would prefer not to edit that package directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to edit the accounts-ui package to add an even handler to a template included in that package. To only attach this handler when the `login` template is being used, just attach it only within the handler for that template:

```js
Template.login.onRendered(function () {
  Template.loginButtons.onRendered(function () {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").remove();
    $("#login-dropdown-list").addClass("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! That code does not work directly but it pointed me in the right direction.

That code gave me the error `Cannot read property 'onRendered' of undefined`. I think it is because `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` does not use the `loginButtons` template, it replaces it with `_loginButtons`.

I finally managed to make it work using `Template._loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown.onRendered`.